# Filling in Missing data, and duplicating others in R

Tags: r, duplicates

My data is in years and not all clusters have data for all the years from 1990 to 2010, so first I want to fill up the missing years for all the ids. Then I want to fill the rest of the fields where I have added the years and create `NA` values for others where I want to predict. How can I go about this in **R**?

```
LAT        LONG    Cluster_ID year
13.5330 -15.4180   1            1990
13.5330 -15.4180   1            1992
13.5330 -15.4180   1            1995
13.5330 -15.4180   1            2010
13.5330 -15.4170   2            1995
13.5330 -15.4170   2            1997
13.5330 -15.4170   2             2005
13.5340 -14.9350   3             2005
13.5340 -14.9350   3             2006
13.5340 -15.9170   4             2010
13.3670 -14.6190   5             2006
```

Comment: how do i do that? am new in the forum. just guide i will accept

Comment: You click the empty check mark next to the Answer you want to accept.

Comment: i saw it and accepted it. do u have an idea on how i go about the above problem? will appreciate any help please

Comment: Click the little green check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You simply create an extra dataframe with all possible combinations, like this :

```
mycomb <- expand.grid(Cluster_ID = unique(mydat$Cluster_ID),
          year = 1990:2010)
```

With that one you can do a merge :

```
merge(mydat,mycomb,all=TRUE)
```

To get the desired result. See also `?expand.grid` and `?merge`.

---

Code tested with :

```
zz <- textConnection('LAT        LONG    Cluster_ID year
13.5330 -15.4180   1            1990
13.5330 -15.4180   1            1992
13.5330 -15.4180   1            1995
13.5330 -15.4180   1            2010
13.5330 -15.4170   2            1995
13.5330 -15.4170   2            1997
13.5330 -15.4170   2             2005
13.5340 -14.9350   3             2005
13.5340 -14.9350   3             2006
13.5340 -15.9170   4             2010
13.3670 -14.6190   5             2006')

mydat <- read.table(zz,header=TRUE)
```

Comment: just a question, i executed the code upto the mergin point. and i find that it has created an array of all the years. i see u have used the textconnection () function but i can not figure out why. in case of my data which has about 20 variables, do i do the same?

Comment: @jonestats The textConnection() is only to read the data you have given us into R so I could test the code. You don't have to execute the code under the line, that's for people that want to try out my solution on some data. See also `?textConnection`

Comment: PS : If the answer solved your problem, you should accept it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: just a follow up. i do i make sure i dont replace the years i had in they year column, so that i just fill in the missing values? Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the solution you got?

Comment: ok, the code created a new column for year, but i wanted it to check in the year variable and only fill in the missing variables. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jonestats read the help files I pointed out, you don't seem to understand what the code does. I have no extra variable `year` in my solution. You probably have some type conversion going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code.I have re-run it and it worked out perfecly. Now i want to fill in the many NAs creating by duplicating the information on the rows with data